# Imported one xlsx file in python, but it throws error

Tags: python, excel, for-loop, import, data-science

I wrote the following code in python.

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.ExcelFile(panda.xlsx)
```

It is giving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    s=pd.ExcelFile("panda1.xls")
  File "C:\Users\nj185047\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 232, in __init__
    import xlrd  # throw an ImportError if we need to
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlrd'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you just tried to install the module required? Just type in the terminal:

```
sudo pip3 install xlrd
```

Comment: I have tried to install in cmd ,it is giving following error,
C:\Users\nj185047\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>sudo pip3 install xlrd
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\nj185047\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>

Comment: Ah, yes. If you are not using Linux, drop "sudo".